# JavaScript Selection Range properties are changing to 0 after setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, selection, contenteditable

I have a contentEditable span inside a React Component, and I am trying to store the caret location so that I can move it back there after the component re-renders and the caret gets moved. But when I call setState the values of Range object change, and I don't understand why... it happens whether I store the range in state, or provide it to setState through a callback.

[image]

It even happens with manually created Ranges. Here is an example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    value: "default"
  }



 handleInput = (event) => {
    let range = document.createRange()
    let node = document.getElementById('myspan').firstChild;

    range.setStart(node, 3)
    range.setEnd(node, 4)

    let value = document.getElementById('myspan').innerText;

    console.log("range before setState:", range)
    this.setState({ value },
      () => {
        console.log("same range object later:", range)
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <span
          id='myspan'
          contentEditable
          onInput={this.handleInput}
        >
          {this.state.value}
        </span>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: After re-render, the cursor position is moved to start of span and so, startoffset and endoffset changes.

Comment: @Sunil The Range object shouldn't keep updating based on my current selection, right? It's just an object that describes some arbitrary range. I edited my post example to be a Range with manually set values and the same thing still happens